# Why is the simpler loop slower?

Tags: python, performance, cpython, python-internals, python-3.11

Called with `n = 10**8`, the simple loop is consistently significantly slower for me than the complex one, and I don't see why:

```
def simple(n):
    while n:
        n -= 1

def complex(n):
    while True:
        if not n:
            break
        n -= 1
```

Some times in seconds:

```
simple 4.340795516967773
complex 3.6490490436553955
simple 4.374553918838501
complex 3.639145851135254
simple 4.336690425872803
complex 3.624480724334717
Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

Here's the looping part of the bytecode as shown by `dis.dis(simple)`:

```
  6     >>    6 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             10 BINARY_OP               23 (-=)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (n)

  5          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             18 POP_JUMP_BACKWARD_IF_TRUE     7 (to 6)
```

And for `complex`:

```
 10     >>    4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_TRUE     2 (to 12)

 11           8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

 12     >>   12 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 BINARY_OP               23 (-=)
             20 STORE_FAST               0 (n)

  9          22 JUMP_BACKWARD           10 (to 4)
```

So it looks like the complex one does more work per iteration (two jumps instead of one). Then why is it faster?

Seems to be a Python 3.11 phenomenon, see the comments.

Benchmark script ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBDoIwEEXjtocws6MQIBI3hIQ7uHBnTIPahkaYklJUzuKGjR7K0wgUotG_mt--_E7__Vm1JlfYdY_GiCB-LZZCqxKMLDnIslLajDOZ5rqtCTlxAXV_UHCKbkKg1zWXBQe0ZhBCkEJk2aMa2NsPvNUN__BSACrznTDooHl2_ssUSoMAibCzW_jzC3vwYG0TDKTj4tQdraDRyvNiayot0VARMoZZyRnzJxICMC4h9trZjMUkjj98OrxwXUuFrq1pamtu7Q0)):

```py
from time import time
import sys

def simple(n):
    while n:
        n -= 1

def complex(n):
    while True:
        if not n:
            break
        n -= 1

for f in [simple, complex] * 3:
    t = time()
    f(10**8)
    print(f.__name__, time() - t)

print('Python:', sys.version)
```

Comment: Where are you running it? On your machine or online? Because on my PC, it works as expected (simple is a little bit faster).

Comment: @XuUserAC On the linked ATO site. What Python version did you use?

Comment: On my 3.11.5 (ubuntu 22.04) the difference is less dramatic, avg 3.38 vs 3.06 (simple vs complex), but still clearly reproducible. I also believe that this may be related to 3.11 update where `POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_TRUE` was introduced - on 3.10.11 `simple` is slightly faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy Python 3.10.13, GCC 11.2.0

Comment: The performance in 3.10 is worse that 3.11 in both cases, so it's almost definitely a result of such change. Since it is very important thing, consider posting this to python issue tracker: if things can be so easily optimized, it can be done by bytecode optimization automatically (transform `while` loop into such comparison with forward jump).

Comment: simple 1.7318181991577148
complex 1.8705182075500488
simple 1.7535889148712158
complex 1.8521349430084229
simple 1.7274327278137207
complex 1.8843679428100586Python: 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2, 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)], On Windows. Simple averages .12 seconds faster than complex.

Comment: @STerliakov Looks like they already optimized it in 3.12, and I suspect they wouldn't do it in 3.11 now, but feel free to create an issue about it if you think different.

Comment: If python was statically typed, this function would become a no-op I guess.

Comment: Backporting to 3.11 would likely have been done had it been easy. Or maybe it has been and it awaits release ...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I checked the source code of the bytecode (python 3.11.6) and found that in the decompiled bytecode, it seems that only `JUMP_BACKWARD` will execute a warmup function, which will trigger [specialization](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-659-specializing-adaptive-interpreter) in python 3.11 when executed enough times:

```c
PyObject* _Py_HOT_FUNCTION
_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault(PyThreadState *tstate, _PyInterpreterFrame *frame, int throwflag)
{
    /* ... */
        TARGET(JUMP_BACKWARD) {
            _PyCode_Warmup(frame->f_code);
            JUMP_TO_INSTRUCTION(JUMP_BACKWARD_QUICK);
        }
    /* ... */
}
```

```c
static inline void
_PyCode_Warmup(PyCodeObject *code)
{
    if (code->co_warmup != 0) {
        code->co_warmup++;
        if (code->co_warmup == 0) {
            _PyCode_Quicken(code);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Among **all** bytecodes, only `JUMP_BACKWARD` and `RESUME` will call `_PyCode_Warmup()`.</sub>

Specialization appears to speed up multiple bytecodes used, resulting in a significant increase in speed:

```c
void
_PyCode_Quicken(PyCodeObject *code)
{
    /* ... */
            switch (opcode) {
                case EXTENDED_ARG:  /* ... */
                case JUMP_BACKWARD: /* ... */
                case RESUME:        /* ... */
                case LOAD_FAST:     /* ... */
                case STORE_FAST:    /* ... */
                case LOAD_CONST:    /* ... */
            }
    /* ... */
}
```

After executing once, the bytecode of `complex` changed, while `simple` did not:

```
In [_]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 complex(10 ** 8)
2.7 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [_]: dis(complex, adaptive=True)
  5           0 RESUME_QUICK             0

  6           2 NOP

  7           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_TRUE     2 (to 12)

  8           8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

  9     >>   12 LOAD_FAST__LOAD_CONST     0 (n)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 BINARY_OP_SUBTRACT_INT    23 (-=)
             20 STORE_FAST               0 (n)

  6          22 JUMP_BACKWARD_QUICK     10 (to 4)
```

```
In [_]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 simple(10 ** 8)
4.78 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [_]: dis(simple, adaptive=True)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              4 POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE     9 (to 24)

  3     >>    6 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             10 BINARY_OP               23 (-=)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (n)

  2          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             18 POP_JUMP_BACKWARD_IF_TRUE     7 (to 6)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Are you able to try `dis(simple, adaptive=True)` on Python 3.12? Carl_M reported `simpler` being faster in 3.12, so maybe it does get optimized as well there.

Comment: @KellyBundy The bytecode of both functions has changed in python 3.12, both of which contain `JUMP_BACKWARD` and trigger specialization after running. `simple` has better performance than `complex` in 3.12.

Comment: Thanks. Would still be nice to see that (the loop parts should suffice (as I did in the question), since that's what's taking the time).

Comment: I guess the `BINARY_OP_SUBTRACT_INT` is the big advantage. If I make `n` a `float` with `f(10.**8)`, then I only get `BINARY_OP_ADAPTIVE` instead and `simpler` seems slightly faster than `complex`. If I additionally add `1.` instead of `1`, I get `BINARY_OP_SUBTRACT_FLOAT` and `complex` is significantly faster again. Another thing: originally, `n` was a global variable, and the speed difference was even larger. Now I see that that's apparently because `LOAD_GLOBAL` adapts to `LOAD_GLOBAL_MODULE`, giving `complex` another advantage.

Comment: Hmm, if `RESUME` calls `_PyCode_Warmup()`, and `simple` does `RESUME`, then why doesn't `simple` get optimized? Is it because it doesn't get executed often enough (it's only once per call of the function)?

Comment: That indeed seems to be the case. After just `for _ in range(8): simple(1)`, it becomes optimized.

Comment: Hmm, actually... I vaguely remember a talk where I think they said Python 3.11 optimizes after 8 runs and Python 3.12 optimizes at the first or second run already. So that might be another reason why `simple` is faster in 3.12.

Comment: Yep, 18:07 to 19:20 in [this talk](https://youtu.be/shQtrn1v7sQ).

Comment: @KellyBundy I checked the source code of Python 3.12 and found that they called specialization for it when creating code objects (which is indeed the case, in 3.12, there were some differences in the results between `dis(simple)` and `dis(simple, adaptive=True)` before `simple` was run).